# Extending Chef Windows Cookbook...DISM limitations

Tags: windows, chef-infra

I'm attempting to install .NET 3.5 framework on WinServer 2012, using Chef.

The ms_dotnet35 cookbook however, doesn't support WinServer 2012.

So I've copied the code it uses in the cookbook to install ([from here](https://github.com/Webtrends/ms_dotnet35/blob/master/recipes/default.rb)) (pardon the formatting):

```
if platform?('windows')
  unless File.exists?('C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v3.5')
      windows_feature 'NetFx3' do
        action :install
      end
    end 

else   Chef::Log.warn('Microsoft Framework .NET 3.5 can only be installed on the Windows platform.') 
end
```

However, there is a snag. When Chef runs, "windows_feature" passes the following commandline:

```
C:\Windows\sysnative\dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3 /norestart
```

It turns out that on WinServer 2012, you need to pass the "/all" argument or you'll get an "A required parent feature may not be enabled." exception ([from here](http://blog.coultard.com/2012/08/install-windows-features-without-access.html))

So now I am looking at the code for "windows_feature" in the windows cookbook ([from here](https://github.com/Webtrends/ms_dotnet35/blob/master/recipes/default.rb)):

```
def install_feature(name)
  # return code 3010 is valid, it indicates a reboot is required
  shell_out!("#{dism} /online /enable-feature /featurename:#{@new_resource.feature_name} /norestart", {:returns => [0,42,127,3010]})
end
```

..where we find the actual call to DISM.

What is the recommended way for me to extend this? Should I just copy the shell_out call and hack the DISM line to get this to work?

I'm new to Chef and want to be following the best practice/correct paradigm. I don't understand why the current implementation of windows_feature doesn't provide a way to enter optional arguments like "/all".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a new recipe in a new cookbook to handle installing .Net Framework 3.5 on Windows Server 2012.

I was able to find the needed files (since I don't have an install disk, I'm on Azure) by dowloading an eval ISO [from here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/dn205287?download=dlm3&url=http://care.dlservice.microsoft.com/dl/download/6/2/A/62A76ABB-9990-4EFC-A4FE-C7D698DAEB96/9600.17050.WINBLUE_REFRESH.140317-1640_X64FRE_SERVER_EVAL_EN-US-IR3_SSS_X64FREE_EN-US_DV9.ISO).

After mounting the ISO I zipped the entire ..\Sources\sxs folder.

my one execute command looks like this:

```
execute "install_net35" do
 command "C:/Windows/sysnative/dism.exe /online /enable-feature /all /featurename:NetFx3 /norestart /limitaccess /source:C:/tempdirectory/sxs"
```

...where "C:/tempdirectory/sxs" is the unzipped file.

I also wrapped the execution in a check for Windows Server 2012:

```
if win_version.windows_server_2012? || win_version.windows_server_2012_r2?
```

..and do a check to see if the framework is already installed (to ensure idempotence):

```
unless File.exists?('C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v3.5')
```

Comment: Can you just put the whole recipe section here?  I like the line by line description, but it'd be nice to see the whole recipe 'chunk'...

Comment: What portion are you having trouble with? I copied the recipe from Git and made only the changes listed above.

Comment: Where did the `win_version` thingy come from? I hadn't seen that before.  I managed to implement the rest. I zipped up the sxs folder and everything.  I was just asking for a 'whole' picture instead of pieces...

Comment: You must have missed the URL in my original post above... https://github.com/Webtrends/ms_dotnet35/blob/master/recipes/default.rb

Comment: Oh, you're the OP... d'oh. Yeah, I missed it. Thanks.

Comment: Accepting my own answer as I got it working and no other user has suggested a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation I believe you should be able to the following (haven't tested it - so feel free to correct me!)

```
if platform?('windows')
  windows_feature 'NetFx3' do
    action :install
    all true
  end
else
  Chef::Log.warn('Microsoft Framework .NET 3.5 can only be installed on the Windows platform.') 
end
```

https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/windows

> all: Boolean. Optional. Default: false. DISM provider only. Forces all dependencies to be installed.

The unless file exists isn't necessary, `windows_feature` only installs unless installed anyway.

Comment: I copied it from your question and the other answers. Confusingly I do think it is .NET 3.5

Comment: In my original question, I mentioned that Chef's wrapper (windows_feature) calling DISM excludes the /all flag, which is needed for WinServer 2012.

Comment: Did you include the line `all true` in the `windows_feature` block?

Comment: It looks like this now shows in the documentation: https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/windows/blob/master/README.md  "Enable .Net 3.5.1 on Server 2012 using repository files on DVD and install all dependencies"  It does appear that you need to provide the path to the sxs files from the DVD (see my current answer). It may take me a few weeks to try this out but if it works I'll choose your answer and edit in the mission portions. Thanks!

Comment: How did you go with this method? I am just starting with a Packer/Vagrant process which uses the Win2k12 R2 iso file and I'm assuming it contains the required source files which can be copied to a local folder and used in later Chef provisioning... Your question+answer is helping a lot!

Comment: I'm still not in a position to try it out. Let me know if it works!